# Vuejs injector : something wrong

Tags: vuejs2

When I try to inject this it shows me: Uncaught Error: Factory Requests - fn must be a [Function]

```
import injector from 'vue-inject'
```

Using plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-inject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `injector.factory` seems to be incorrect, according to examples in [Github vue-inject](https://github.com/jpex-js/vue-inject#factoryname-dependencies-function).
The signature is **factory(name, [dependencies], function)**, but you have **factory(name, [dependencies, function])**.